# How to update node properties from a page in Umbraco 7 using razor

Tags: razor, umbraco7

I have been hunting around for a solution to this, but cannot find anything for version 7.

I just have to update a date property on an Umbraco 7 node. (not the publish date)
Then I need to tell umbraco to republish the page/update caching.

In the code below the individual node is "item", if it finds the item has a checkbox property set to true then it should increment the date by 1 year.

```
if(item.annual.ToString()=="True")
{
    item.deadlineDate = item.deadlineDate.AddYears(1);
}
```

Any and all suggestions gratefully welcome,

Regards,
Damien Holley

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ContentService is your friend :-) https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/ContentService

With it, you can both save and publish content.

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob at Umbraco, which part specifically deals with updating the variable "deadlineDate" on the item? I found a few bits on the linked page that dealt with publishing an object, but nothing for the updating.

Comment: If you have a Content object ( https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Models/Content ), you can update properties like item.SetValue("deadlineDate", DateTime.Whatever) and then save and publish using the ContentService.

Comment: Updating a property using the contentservice would look something like this (not tested): var contentService = Services.ContentService;
var content = contentService.GetById(item.Id);
content.SetValue(deadlineDate, item.deadlineDate.AddYears(1));
contentService.SaveAndPublishWithStatus(content);

Comment: Yeah, something like that if item isn't already a Content object. Also, SetValue("deadlineDate", ...) <- remember the quotation marks.

Comment: Cheers guys, I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your `item` variable is dynamic, you first need to to pass its id to the management API service:

```
var contentService = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService;
var content = contentService.GetById(item.Id);
content.SetValue("deadlineDate", item.deadlineDate.AddYears(1));
contentService.SaveAndPublish(content);
```

This will persist the value and make it available elsewhere in the application. It will also update using the admin user's account, so if you want the audit trail to show something else, you need to use pass the user id to the `SaveAndPublish` method.

Finally, you need to be careful with using the [Management API](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/) within views. Not only is it possible lose data due to frontend user actions but it can also lead to performance issues as the `ContentService` will always hit the database, unlike the query APIs (`IPublishedContent` or `DynamicPublishedContent`).

**EDIT**: I've just noticed the comments in [Jannik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583208/1598534) which more or less provide the same answer.

Comment: Cheers,I appreciate the help